# Chrome - Uncaught (in promise) Error: The message port closed before a response was received in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

Why do these errors happen when I clicked something on the page then that it renders in the console...

[image: Error in Chrome]

Comment: It seems like you have not catch Promise error properly.Use Try/Catch block to handle promise error if you are using async/await or use .catch block if you are using .then block.

Comment: I am use try catch method these error only occurs in chrome not any other browser like opera firefox